# common image on page with tab bar contents of onsen UI

Tags: html, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, onsen-ui, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am trying to implement a page with tab bar in onsen UI. Where I am able to switch pages between "Tab1" and "Tab2".

But my question is **how can I place the Image which will be present in both tab bar pages and only remaining part of the page will switch.**

For Example as given in wire frame, "common image content" should be present when user clicks any of the tab, only content "tab1 content" and "tab2 content" are gets changed.
[image]
[image]

Please let me know any work around for this ?

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: From `onsen-template` component can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could place a toolbar on top of your tabbar. It is persistent, you can make it transparent and you can put an image into it.

Example from the [Docs](http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#UsingTabBar):

```
<ons-page>
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">Page Title</div>
  </ons-toolbar>
  <ons-tabbar position="top">
    <ons-tab page="page1.html" icon="fa-square"></ons-tab>
    <ons-tab page="page2.html" icon="fa-square"></ons-tab>
    <ons-tab page="page3.html" icon="fa-square"></ons-tab>
  </ons-tabbar>
</ons-page>
```